# Running multiple instances of a Java app (Salesforce DataLoader) on a single W7 machine?

Tags: java, salesforce, windows-7-x64

My first post, be gentle.

I'm primarily a Mac user and I use LexiLoader (the Mac port of DataLoader, a Windows Java app) to administer Salesforce. Because I'm often managing data in both our Prod and Dev environments, it's a pain going into LL settings to change the URL from login.salesforce to test.salesforce and then back again, constantly throughout the day. So I just duplicated the entire LL folder to see if it created a separate standalone instance of the app that could maintain its own settings. And it works beautifully.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in W7 and I'm a bit lost. I installed Dataloader twice, making sure the second instance saved to a separate program folder. And I've got two distinct shortcuts...one points to the .jar in the first folder and the other points to the .jar file in the second. I launched the first, set the url to Dev and closed. Then opened up the other one and it was also set to Dev. So I set it back to Prod. Opened up the first and it's set back to Prod, too.

Does this mean that even though there are two distinct instances of the app, they share the same settings file somewhere?

Is there a way to maintain two instances of the same java app in W7, each with their own distinct settings?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sreenshot.]

Go to the file *config.properties* under target folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\target\config.properties

Change the required URL at below property.It will work.

***sfdc.endpoint=https://login.salesforce.com***

Thanks,

Naveen

[AutoRABIT](http://www.autorabit.com)